# Does a shared variable have a default lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a program iterating through a vector of Objects and applying a function to each element of the vector. This is a comparison between each of the elements as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(i, myVector)
for(i = 0 ; i < myVector.size() ; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1 ; j < bdd.size() ; j++) {
        myVector[i]->compare(*myVector[j]); //
    }
}
```

I do not modify the vector. I add a value in the attribute of each Object element. Therefore, I think I do not need any locks for that use.

**Here is my problem :** using several threads (tested from one to eight threads) does not speed up the process. I was wondering if the fact that `myVector` is a shared variable would automatically lock the variable so that it cannot be used by several threads at the same time.

Comment: there is nothing like a *default lock*, shared variables are shared, meaning you need to take care of possible data races on your own

Comment: Piotr S. is right about the (lack of) locking. As to the absence of speedup, that's tricky. Perhaps your cache lines are all over the place.

Comment: Since you're only reading and not writing then your don't have to wory about a lock. What's the value of `myVector.size()`? You definitely don't want `i` to be shared but OpenMP will make it private even though you told it to be shared.

Comment: You are right about `i` that should be private, thanks ! `myVector.size()` is around 3000, why ? And do you mean about cache lines ?

Comment: well it seems that one of the comparison is muuuuuch longer than the other ones (about 1000 times longer)... so that explains that no matter how many threads I put, the one that is computing this comparison will always be the one slowing the whole process !

Comment: In such cases you should add the `schedule(dynamic,nn)` clause, where `nn` is the size of the iteration chunks. Experiment with different values, e.g. `1`, `5`, `10`, etc. and see which gives you the best performance. Smaller values result in better load balancing but the OpenMP overhead is higher.